# Renting a car in central Asia as an inexperienced driver

Tags: car-rentals, central-asia

I just got my driving licence last month, and am looking forward to exploring parts of the world that have seemed hard to access without a car. On the top of my list is central Asia, in particular Uzbekistan, Kyrgyzstan and southern Kazakhstan. Unfortunately all car rental agencies I found online required a minimum of 1 year of driving licence ownership, often even 2. Is there any agency in this region, doesn’t need to be a big or reputable name, that will trust me with a car without having to wait for 11 months?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is a large area. Can you target the city where you arrive?

Comment: Truly learning to drive (and you haven't by any means done so yet) is hard enough without adding an unfamiliar environment.

Comment: If you only just got a driving licence you might be well out of your depth in a foreign country. Perhaps consider making the adventure with an experienced overland tour operator, or to boldly go with shared taxis and local buses.

Comment: @WeatherVane I haven’t decided yet, most likely Tashkent or Almaty, though I don’t mind having to travel a bit to get a vehicle. And thanks for the advice, but I decidedly do not want to travel around this region in this way.

Comment: There’s a reason why car rental agencies have this requirement - it’s called risk management. Young and inexperienced drivers have been shown to have the highest rates of crash involvement, injuries to themselves and others and deaths of others in crashes in which they are involved.

Comment: Not a good idea IMHO.

Comment: I haven't been to those countries but I know that in Ashgabat, Turkmenistan children ride unrestrained between the front seats, babies are 'seated' on the passenger seat restrained by gravity alone and women aren't allowed to drive until they're 30. Most people drive too fast for the conditions and approximately every third to fourth day we would come across a serious crash scene. Just an anecdote though and I'd expect the countries you listed to be better (more political freedom tends to equate to more self awareness and critical thought)

Answer (score 5):

The rule about having had a driving license for a given amount of time is not there to inconvenience new drivers.
It is there because new drivers are more likely to get into accidents. The risk of accidents goes up when there is a different car, a different environment, different rules of the road, different driving practices and different kind of roads.

Going to Central Asia you will run into most or all of those risk factors.
So the chances of a reputable rental company renting to you will be low. If they do they will charge a very huge premium to cover the much higher insurance fee.

And it is not only the length of having had your driving license. There is also often a rule for a minimum age. Often 21 but 25 is not unheard of.

Some people will rent to everybody, but those people are either renting out cars which are not worth the money you pay for them or people who are real crooks (as in dangerous to do business with) or really desperate people who may rent out their own car in the hope they get enough money to pay the rent or even food (often having poor quality cars due to not having the money.)
If you decide to go with the kind of rental 'company' that rent out cars to people who do not have at least one year driving experience make sure you have a travel insurance that do come to your rescue when your car breaks down.
Even more important when you go off the beaten track.

I do warn you against using the 'does not matter how long you have had your license, does not matter how old you are' kind of rental. But if you feel you are willing to take the risk, you can find the companies in the small ads in the local news papers. These days you can also find them in the internet equivalent, the local listings of 'things for sale'. And if you do not speak the local language, getting the help of a little bit shady hostel owner may help, but will make the situation a bit more risky as there is one more person to rip you off.

Comment: Experience is often underrated by those who have none :-)